# Exposing Neo4j Bolt using Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: neo4j, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, bolt

I'm trying to build a Neo4j Learning Tool for some of our Trainings. I want to use Kubernetes to spin up a Neo4j Pod for each participant to use. Currently I struggle exposing the bolt endpoint using an Ingress and I don't know why.
Here are my deployment configs:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neo4j
  namespace: learn
  labels:
    app: neo-manager
    type: database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: neo-manager
      type: database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neo-manager
        type: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: neo4j
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: neo4j:3.5.6
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7474
            - containerPort: 7687
              protocol: TCP
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: neo4j-service
  namespace: learn
  labels:
    app: neo-manager
    type: database
spec:
  selector:
    app: neo-manager
    type: database
  ports:
    - port: 7687
      targetPort: 7687
      name: bolt
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
      name: client
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neo4j-ingress
  namespace: learn
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: learn.neo4j.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: neo4j-service
              servicePort: 7474
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: learn
data:
  7687: "learn/neo4j-service:7687"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: learn
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.16
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --tcp-services-configmap=${POD_NAMESPACE}/tcp-services
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

The client gets exposed nicely and it reachable under `learn.neo4j.com` but I don't know where to point it to to connect to the DB using bolt. Whatever I try, it fails saying `ServiceUnavailable: Websocket Connection failure` (`WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused` in the console).
What am I missing?

Comment: What ingress controller do you have in your cluster?

Comment: The nginx-ingress

Comment: Do you mean the "nginx ingress controller" https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I though it was just called "nginx-ingress"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It automatically tries to connect to port 7687 by default - if you enter the connection url `http://learn.neo4j.bolt.com:80` (or https), it works.

Comment: I might resolve to that if I can't manage to get bolt to work.
But I'd rather use bolt

Comment: It *does* use bolt under the hood by opening a websocket and transfering websocket-frames.

Comment: Oh, it does? I didn't know that. That's kinda cool, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `nginx-ingress-controller` by default creates http(s) proxies only.

In your case you're trying to use a different protocol (bolt) so you need to configure your ingress controller in order for it to make a TCP proxy.

In order to do so, you need to create a configmap (in the nginx-ingress-controller namespace) similar to the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  7687: "<your neo4j namespace>/neo4j-service:7687"
```

Then, make sure your ingress controller has the following flag in its command:

```
--tcp-services-configmap tcp-services
```

This will make your nginx-ingress controller listen to port 7687 with a TCP proxy.

You can delete the `neo4j-bolt-ingress` Ingress, that's not going to be used.

Of course you have to ensure that the ingress controller correctly exposes the 7687 port the same way it does with ports 80 and 443, and possibly you'll have to adjust the settings of any firewall and load balancer you might have.

Source: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Comment: I'll try that, thank you! But how do I reach that service from the outside, if I don't use an ingress anymore, so I don't specify a host? Meaning, to what would I have to point the Noe4j Client to connect?

Comment: The hostname you specify in the Ingress resource only makes sense in an http virtualhost. There is no HTTP here so the hostname makes no real sense.
You can access your bolt endpoint using any hostname that somwhow reaches your ingress controller. Please be aware that you'll have to use port 7687 and not 80.

Comment: I've updated my config files regarding my understanding. Sadly it's still not working

Comment: How do you reach your ingress controller from outside the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used kubernetes ingress in this context before, but I think that when you use HTTP or HTTPS to connect to Neo4J, you still require external availability to connect to the the bolt port (7687). Does your setup allow for that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. I want to expose the client (port 7474) and the bolt port (7687) so that the participants can call learn.neo4j.com to get the client and point it to learn.neo4j.bolt.com to connect it to the Neo4j-DB using bolt. So basically I need external availability on both 7474 and 7687.

Comment: hi, [Urr4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4558848/urr4) was this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using multi-path mapping in your Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: neo4j-ingress
  namespace: learn
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: learn.neo4j.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /browser
            backend:
              serviceName: neo4j-service
              servicePort: 7474
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: neo4j-service
              servicePort: 7687
```

You should then be able to access the UI at [learn.neo4j.com/browser](https://learn.neo4j.com/browser). The bolt Connect URL would have to specified as:

> bolt+s://learn.neo4j.com:443/